# Define trailing stop in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, forex

Is there a possibility in the pinescript code to include an initial stop order that is, for example, at 65 pips and then updates according to price changes with the trailling stop?

Can define and initial stop loss and after chage this stop loss with the trailing stop

Comment: Please show what you tried or reproduce the unexpected behavior you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.
Try [strategy.exit](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html?highlight=trail_offset#strategy-exit) with *trail_offset*

Something like this:

```
// Return the entry price for the latest closed trade.
currEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)

//Stop loss (specified in ticks)
SL_ticks = 65

//Trailling Stop (specified in ticks)
TR_ticks = 10


if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(
      id               = 'Long Exit',
      from_entry       = 'Long',
      loss             = SL_ticks,
      trail_price      = currEntryPrice,
      trail_offset     = TR_ticks)
```